# problem with unlocking user-password secured PDF

Tags: pdf, passwords, adobe-reader

I have a PDF file protected by password - I know the **correct user password**. The problem is, that I am only able to open it on Windows Adobe Reader. Every other PDF viewer (also Linux command prompts tools for removing passwords) returns the information that password is wrong.

Potential cause: password is long (30 characters) and **contains non-Latin (Polish) characters** (like ł ó ę ć ź ą). I tried things like Unicode to ASCII converter, but it does not work.

**Has anybody idea why it works only in Acrobat? I just want to open this document on Linux.** The best would be to remove password.

EDIT: document is secured by 128-bit AES, Acrobat mention that "can be opened by Acrobat 7.0 or newer". Printing, copying, etc is not allowed.

EDIT2: thanks for helping in comments, I tried SumatraPDF and it works - but only allow to print this to non-searchable images pdf.
I checked that it is based on mupdf engine, but mupdf on Linux cannot deal with this file - it crash.
**Sumatra has open source, do anybody knows how to edit it to print to PDF in normal way?**

Comment: According to the spec for old (pre-PDF 2.0) encryption algorithms: "The password string is generated from host system codepage characters (or system scripts) by first
converting the string to PDFDocEncoding. If the input is Unicode, first convert to a codepage encoding,
and then to PDFDocEncoding for backward compatibility." Thus, platform dependency and unclear conversions were part of the design. So simply don't use non-ASCII characters in passwords with those old algorithms. The game changed with AES-256 in PDF 2.0.

Comment: I have just tried Windows Foxit and SumatraPDF - and I am in a great shock, SumatraPDF works. My college friends and I have tried so many PDF readers and none of them works.

Comment: In this case, do you have any idea what tool could also deal with password and print it as searchable text?

Answer (score 0):

SumatraPDF uses MuPDF as its engine for several formats such as ePub HTML and of course PDF. It can store (not remove) a know password as a hash so no need to keep inputting for everyday reading or adding comments to a PDF.

So if as suggested by @mkl using the password with local characters on a local PC may work in SumatraPDF it should work in MuPDF-GL which is a more basic viewer. Spoiler, certainly I can remove my own simple 9 character encrypted [challenge.pdf](https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/AppNotes/protected.pdf) (8 sequentially alphabetic characters are a known semi random sequence) to save in MuPDF as unprotected.pdf, but nobody has cracked it yet :-)

*However* MuPDF-GL has many more powerful abilities hidden under the surface.

Using MuPDF-GL you should be able to open the file when it prompts for that password. then press <kbd>A</kbd> which starts the annotator (you dont need to add anything) but simply change the save as settings.

So in this case if there were errors it will have fixed any needed to re-save but first switch OFF incremental and set encryption to none. There is no guarantee this will work for all cases but worth a try.
[image]

***IF mupdf-gl does not work for you on linux you can try***

[MuTool](https://mupdf.com/releases/index.html) `mutool draw -p password -o unprotected.pdf protected.pdf`

OR [qpdf](https://qpdf.sourceforge.io/) which can also rebuild a PDF with different restrictions given the correct input password(s).

`qpdf --password=myverylongstring!"^$% --decrypt protected.pdf unprotected.pdf`

or if the password may cause commandline UTF problems save it as first line of a text file and use

`qpdf -password-file=password.txt --decrypt protected.pdf unprotected.pdf`

**Lastly** if you wish to print a pdf file on Linux you have two potential options as readers OLD Evince works for me on Windows 32bit but for 64bit I prefer nightly cutting edge Okular.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I have tried mupdf before. It works on linux and I can open other PDF files. But in case of my file, while opening and writing correct password i got this error:
`
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  12 (X_ConfigureWindow)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  678
  Current serial number in output stream:  679
`
then mupdf crashes.
As i mentioned, this password contains 30 characters, and many of them are non Latin letters